# Display file size next to file link

Tags: 8, theming

I'm trying to override the file-link.html.twig to display the size next to the file link (also the file MIME type, but I think I can figure that out once I figure out how to display the size) but so far I've been failing spectacularly. I assume this must be super simple and I'm missing something obvious.

Using kint($variables) in the function themename_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) I see the filesize:

```
$args array (1)
array (15
'file' => Drupal\file\Entity\File(27) 
"contents" tab:
    protected values -> array(13)
    'filesize' => array(1)
    'x-default' => string(7) "2245389"
```

But I can't figure out how to turn this into a variable I can use in a template file.

I tried following [How can I override template_preprocess_file_link function?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/258058/how-can-i-override-template-preprocess-file-link-function) but then I couldn't figure out what was suppose to be the variable to use in the template file. Also, his "code" just seems to be same as what is on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/template_preprocess_file_link/8.6.x.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you are asking for, but you can use tokens to display the file size and mime type (handy if you are using display suite, for example). `[file:size]` & `[file:mime]` - or you can access them in the twig if you install Twig Tweak `drupal_token([file:size])` -- https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak

Comment: How do I use token in a node template? I tried this for a referenced media file but it doesn't work? `{{ drupal_token('node.myfield.entity|file:size') }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `HOOK_preprocess_field(&$variables)`:

```
/**
 * Implements HOOK_preprocess_field().
 *
 * @inheritdoc
 */
function HOOK_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  // Check that field_name is set.
  if (isset($element['#field_name'])) {
    // Checking for field_name, but could check for field_type.
    if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_name') {
      // Set our file size to a variable.
      $fileSize = $element[0]['#file']->filesize->value;
      // Edit our title for the field display.
      $element[0]['#file']->filename->value = $element[0]['#file']->filename->value . ' ' . $fileSize;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Using `HOOK_preprocess_file_link(&$variables)`:

```
/**
 * Add the "file-link.html.twig" template to your theme and adjust as needed.
 * 
 * Twig variables:
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileBundle }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileCreatedTime }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileChangedTime }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileFid }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileLangcode }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileMime }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileName }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileOwnerId }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileOwnerName }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileOwnerUserPictureUrl }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileSize }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileSizeFormatted }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileStatus }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileUrl }}
 * - {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileUuid }}
 */

function HOOK_preprocess_file_link(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['file'])) {
    $variables['fileLinkDisplay'] = [
      'fileBundle' => $variables['file']
        ->bundle(),
      'fileCreatedTime' => $variables['file']
        ->getCreatedTime(),
      'fileChangedTime' => $variables['file']
        ->getChangedTime(),
      'fileFid' => $variables['file']
        ->fid->value,
      'fileLangcode' => $variables['file']
        ->langcode->value,
      'fileMime' => $variables['file']
        ->getMimeType(),
      'fileName' => $variables['file']
        ->getFilename(),
      'fileOwnerId' => $variables['file']
        ->getOwnerId(),
      'fileOwnerName' => $variables['file']
        ->getOwner()->name->value,
      'fileOwnerUserPictureUrl' => file_create_url($variables['file']
        ->getOwner()->user_picture->entity->uri->value),
      'fileSize' => $variables['file']
        ->getSize(),
      'fileSizeFormatted' => format_size($variables['file']
        ->getSize()),
      'fileStatus' => $variables['file']
        ->status->value,
      'fileUrl' => file_create_url($variables['file']
        ->getFileUri()),
      'fileUuid' => $variables['file']
        ->uuid->value,
    ];
  }
}
```

See https://gitlab.com/prestosaurus/file-link-display/blob/master/file_link_display.module

Then your `file-link.html.twig` might look like:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for a link to a file.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_file_link()
 */
#}
{{ attach_library('classy/file') }}
<span{{ attributes }}>{{ icon }} {{ link }} {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileSize }} {{ fileLinkDisplay.fileMime }}</span>
```

Comment: In a preprocess function, you never use `echo`, not even for debugging purposes.

Comment: True, the echo I have is just so the user can see the result of `$element['#title']` and that it is not quantified or altered in other processes. Do not leave this in your function.

Comment: What would you hope to achieve with this code? Currently you're just altering some variables within a function, you're not changing anything that would be altered in the template

Comment: I updated my answer a bit. The `#title` was just what I was working with. The first function will rewrite the label of the field and append the `filesize` value.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I'm not sure its all clicking in my head.
Why "HOOK_preprocess_field" and not "HOOK_preprocess_file_link"?

Comment: I added that hook to my answer, it will allow you to send the file size value to your `file-link.html.twig` Twig template.

Comment: Thank you, this totally helped and worked. And for someone like me who comes across this, if you want to format the size do this:

`$variables['fileSize'] = format_size($variables['file']->filesize->value);`